# How to create instance of my own class using NSInvocation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dealloc, nsinvocation

I am trying to create a new instance of my custom class (custom `init` method call, with a `BOOL` parameter) dynamically. How can I use `NSInvocation` to do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
NSMethodSignature* signature = [NSClassFromString(className) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector: sel];
NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: signature];
[invocation setTarget: [NSClassFromString(className) alloc]];
[invocation setSelector:sel];
[invocation setArgument:&value atIndex:2];
[invocation invoke];
[invocation getReturnValue:&obj];
```

Above sample throws error in line `[invocation invoke];` error is `"message sent to deallocated instance"`.

Comment: Are you declaring the `value` and `obj` parameters that are being used for return values?

Comment: Yes, I have declared them.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use NSInvocation? Would `[[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init]` work for you? Or perhaps if your classes share the same custom init method: `[[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] initWithValue:value]`

Comment: Where are you adding them?

Comment: I have custom init which takes boolean. I need to dynamically create instance by calling the init that actually takes boolean. perform selector would nt help as it takes Object, whereas bool is not an object.

Comment: Why? Why are you not using a superclass or a protocol to specify the generic interface and then using that to create the instance?

Comment: What do you mean to dynamically create instance? Why not just do a direct call, or delayed call via block? What are you trying to do?

Comment: NSObject *obj; BOOL value=YES; This is how i am declaring both variables above the code snip given above

Comment: @Wain I want an reusable implementation, which can create instance for any class(name will be an argument to use this implementation). performselector would help if we have init objects. But in case if I have BOOL that needs to be passed for init-call, then performselector wouldn't help, hence i have gone for NSInvocation.

Comment: @user516542 Why not do `Class cls = NSClassFromString(className); id instance = [[cls alloc] initWithBool:value];`?

Comment: @user516542 If you make `NSZombieEnabled=YES` you will easily detect which object is the actual problem here. It is very possible the problem is inside `init...` method, because your code as it is seems fine: unless some of involved objects are already deallocated, it should work well.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work because the `NSInvocation` doesn't retain the target or any arguments unless you tell it to (with `retainArguments`). So, you `alloc` an instance and then it gets destroyed before you `invoke` the `NSInvocation`.

Alternatively, create an instance variable and store the `alloc`'d instance there, then pass that to the `NSInvocation`.

Comment: His code does `invoke` right away, before anything can possibly be deallocated.

Comment: @hamstergene: It's deallocated because there are no strong references to the object. `setTarget:` does not retain it.